# Bibtex entry for white papers and technical reports.

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have writing my first Latex document so this may be bit of a beginners questions. I have using the natbib package for agsm harvard style bibliography in my report. I have to cite a few reports I found online and didn't find any readymade bibtex entry. I guess I will have to write it myself. But I am confused as to how to do this.

The first one is a white paper my the UMTS forum. I give the link here [Mobile Broadband Evolution](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.umts-forum.org%2Fcomponent%2Foption%2Ccom_docman%2Ftask%2Cdoc_download%2Fgid%2C2089%2FItemid%2C12%2F&rct=j&q=Mobile%20Broadband%20Evolution%3A%20the%20roadmap%20from%20HSPA%20to%20LTE&ei=QHjuTMbdKIqYOojf3awK&usg=AFQjCNFegRMD5Ghq2SYvsH6OA8ce4CJ2fw&sig2=gugsF5gm1IQNz2fnL0fKqA&cad=rja)

Under what category do I put these and what would be the bibtex entry?

The next one is a [technical report](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/pax/uploads/pdf/publication/1290/ifi-techreport20100001.pdf)

I found the bibtex entry for the whole technical report, which is:

```
@techreport{instance1290,
     title = {{Mobile Systems IV}},
     author = {Burkhard Stiller and Thomas Bocek and Fabio Hecht and Guilherme Machado and Peter Racz and Martin Waldburger},
     group = {csg},
     year = {2010},
     institution = {University of Zurich, Department of Informatics},
     month = {01},
     Date-Added = {2010-01-11 10:05:52},
     Date-Modified = {2010-07-22 12:08:45}
}
```

but I need to cite one of the chapters from that report. Which has its own author.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 63):

Basically a white paper is a technical report. At [www.cse.msu.edu](http://www.cse.msu.edu/cgi-user/web/tech/document?ID=646&BibTex=Y) you will find this example:

```
@TECHREPORT{MSU-CSE-06-2,
  AUTHOR =        {R. Behrends and L. K. Dillon and S. D. Fleming and
               R. E. K. Stirewalt},
  TITLE =         {White paper: Programming according to the fences and gates
                   model for developing assured, secure software
                   systems},
  NUMBER =        {MSU-CSE-06-2},
  INSTITUTION =   {Department of Computer Science, Michigan State University},
  ADDRESS =       {East Lansing, Michigan},
  ABSTRACT =      {This white paper describes extensions to our work on the
                   Synchronization Units Model (Szumo) to address the
                   access-control problem in systems assembled dynamically from
                   trusted and untrusted components. Our extension employs
                   explicitly declared design contracts, the semantics of which
                   are founded on Landwehr's model of fences and gates.
                   },
  KEYWORDS =      {access control, security, contracts, Szumo},
  NOTE =          {},
  MONTH =         {January},
  YEAR  =         {2006},
  AUTHOR1_URL =   {http://www.poker-ping.info},
  AUTHOR1_EMAIL = {kel@wondering-jons.com},
  AUTHOR1_URL =   {},
  AUTHOR1_EMAIL = {behrends@cse.msu.edu},
  AUTHOR2_URL =   {Sle},
  AUTHOR2_EMAIL = {Poker Ping},
  AUTHOR2_URL =   {http://www.cse.msu.edu/~stire},
  AUTHOR2_EMAIL = {stire@cse.msu.edu},
  PAGES =         {3},
  FILE  =         {/user/web/htdocs/publications/tech/TR/MSU-CSE-06-2.ps},
  URL   =         {},
  CONTACT =       {stire@cse.msu.edu}
}
```

Comment: The `type` field may also be of interest to some - if this is unprovided, some bibliography styles will default `type` to "Technical Report" (or similar). You can add `type = {White Paper}` to mitigate (or whatever type it is).