# Pages and publiser attibutes not shows from the bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

The pages and publisher attribute are not shown from the BibTeX.

elsarticle-template-num.tex file:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
several other countries\cite{R1}.
```

BibTeX file :

```
@techreport{R1,
author = {Organization, World Health},
mendeley-groups = {Covid 19 Chest Xray},
pages = {9 p.},
publisher = {World Health Organization},
title = {{Coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19): situation report, 51}},
type = {Technical documents}
}
```

Reference file from complied :
[image]

Comment: `@techreport` normally does not have a `publisher`. Instead it has a field called `institution` that plays a similar role.

Comment: `author = {Organization, World Health},` is wrong. "Corporate authors" must be protected with an extra pair of curly braces: `author = {{World Health Organization}},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. Also I would probably drop the `institution` if it coincides with the `author` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe for your solution. Can you tell me why the page number not showing in the reference?

Comment: I also used this bibtex from this question's answer -   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/bibtex-entry-for-white-papers-and-technical-reports    - but till it does not show the page number.

Comment: Since `@techreport` refers to a single work, you do not need a page number to find the work itself. The BibTeX standard styles and also the `elsarticle` styles simply do not have a field for the number of pages here (which is usually not very relevant anyway). If it is so important to you that you need to show it, put it into the `note` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe for your kind help. Learn a lot from you. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120402/discussion-between-md-asif-iqbal-fahim-and-moewe).